# What type of a wall mount is needed for an old TV?

Tags: television, anchor

I have an old Onida TV that doesn't have the standard 4-hole VESA mount.

[image]

It only has these two <strike>hinges</strike> slots of some sort.

What kind of wall mount would hold it in place on a concrete wall? (It would be nice if I could also swivel and tilt the TV)

Comment: They are known as keyhole slots.  One or two screws are put into something like a wall but the screwheads are left out a bit.  The tv or whatever is then lowered down onto the screwheads to catch and hold.  I imagine you can attach/screw a piece of plywood to a vesa mount and use it that way.  The tv will not be locked on, a simple push up and it will fall off.

Comment: Bit of a lifehack, depending on the size of the TV, scanning/photocopying or sticking a piece of painter tape and taking a rubbing of the holes is really nice for getting a neat, accurate template for dripping the holes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mount on a pair of screws like a picture.  Buy screws with heads that are the biggest that can fit into the larger part of the mounting hole, and shafts the biggest that can slide into the smaller part.  About 2 inch long, with good concrete wall anchors.  Drill carefully to space them accurately.

**Do not** use a tilt or swivel mount with this TV.  It is not designed for one, it will break off or fall off if handled regularly by people.

Comment: I would also suggest screws with a flat area underneath the head, or to use washers.

Comment: Yes, a pan-head screw would be better than a countersunk one but it will be "challenging" to slide the TV onto a screw in the wall if there is a loose washer there that has to go into the keyhole with the screw head.  You need a screw with the right sized head.